# Swift Array to get all elements+

Tags: swift, swift3

I am new to programming and Swift. I'm trying to get all the elements from an array but I'm getting only last one.

Here is my code

```
for i in 0..<ArrayallFriends.count {
    let objectuser =  self.ArrayallFriends.objectAtIndex(i) as! User

    BFD.lblfrndname.text = objectuser.fullName as String
    BFD.btndelete.hidden=false
    BFD.btnflag.hidden=false
    BFD.btnblock.hidden=false
    self.loggedInCellArray.addObject(BFD)
}
```

I'm getting only `[6]`
what changes are needed to get output `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Comment: How you want to get the output, You just want to print it? Or you want to create a function that returns an array with all the values?

Comment: 1) what is `BFD` - is it a class instance? If so you are overwriting it. You may need to create a different instance each time through the `for` loop.
2) what is `loggedInCellAray`? - I assume it's an `NSArray`. Why are you not using Swift arrays?

Comment: ... and if it is NOT a class but a variable, then give it a better name.  The same issue applies to ArrayallFriends, which would be better as friendsList, or friendsArray, or just friends, but ArrayallFriends is the naming convention you would use for a class or struct definition

Answer (score -1):

instead of for i in 0... try

```
for user in self.ArrayallFriends {
     let objectuser = user as! User
     ///rest of code
}
```